# compiling error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'char' when trying to assign array to array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that will have a list of lists like so

{{}, {}, {}}

where each list will be a y value and what is inside them the x value.

When I try to compile my program I get the error in the title.

The relevant part of the program:

```
void genRand(){

int x;
int y;

cin >> x;
cin >> y;

int world[y];


for(int yv = 0; yv == y; yv++){

    char ylist[x];

    for(int xv = 0; xv == x; xv++){

        char symbols[2] = {'-', '#'};

        int randIndex = rand() % 2;

        ylist[xv] = symbols[randIndex];
    }

    world[yv] = ylist;


}


error: assigning to 'int' from
      incompatible type 'int [x]'
                world[yv] = ylist;
                            ^
```

How can I fix this? It works fine in the line above it but suddenly breaks when attempting it again.

Comment: 1) VLAs are non-standard C++. 2) You are trying to assign the **array** of `char`s, to a **single** `int`. What would be the meaning of such assignment? Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of coding randomly. 3) Such error is impossible with the code shown, since the shown error complains about `int []` to `int` conversion, while the code tries to assign `char []` to `int`.

Comment: I'm trying to index the world list by going world[yv]. So it would work every time it goes through the loop by [have list, fill list with characters, put that list inside bigger list, have list, etc.]

Comment: You still didn't explain, what do you expect to happen, when you assign an array of `char`s to a single `int`. Consider learning from [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), as I already mentioned.

Comment: Also, the middle part of a for-loop is a while-condition, not an until-condition. So it would work better using `!=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put a `string` value into `int` array.

`int world[y]` should be `string` array, so change it to `string world[y]`

Comment: If `ylist` is a C-string, who puts a terminating `\0` in it? Your change leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`ylist` -> character array type

```
char ylist[x];
```

`world[yv]` -> integer

```
int world[y];
```

The problem that causes the error is that we are setting a character array type to an integer type.

We can fix this by actually changing data types in such a way that what we are setting and the handler is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with conversions reported:

> error: assigning to 'int' from
>
> incompatible type 'int [x]'
>
> world[yv] = ylist;

So remembering that an array is just multiple data values stored in a contiguous block of memory. A 'char' and an 'int' are formatted in memory completely differently so if you try read them as a different data type you are going to get unintended results. Physically a 'char' is only 1 byte in memory while an 'int' is 4, so if you had an ASCII number to be stored as an integer number you would need to convert it prior to storing it as an int.

I believe this could solve the issue you have:

```
    int num = static_cast<int>(letter); // if letter='A', num=10
```

[NOTE] - ASCII number values start at 0 to 9 and then alpha characters. It would be a good idea to think about using exception handling to catch bad data.